# How to start really spring boot application before selenium test running with JUnit4?

Tags: spring, selenium, spring-boot, junit, junit4

For my unit test, I use these annotations : 

**@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)


@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)**

My probleme happen when I tried to test the GUI with selenium. 
In my gui test, I called some page and verify the content of the html messages.

I don't need a mock, I need to start application before my test. 
What is an elegant way todo that ?

What really do the annotation **@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)**, It don't start the application and according to logs, It try to launch the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of the annotations `@WebIntegrationTest`, `@RunWith`, and 
`@SpringApplicationConfiguration`. You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/web-programming-examples/blob/master/spring-test-selenium/src/test/java/io/github/web/springtest/SpringTest.java).

Comment: Annotation WebIntegrationTest and SpringApplicationConfiguration are depreciated, but the solution works.